# Is there any solution for Util error in MySQL react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Whenever I try to run react native project, I get util module error in MySQL.

Error:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module util from C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js: util could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules\mysql\node_modules
node_modules
..\..\node_modules
7 | var SqlString        = require('./protocol/SqlString');
8 | var Query            = require('./protocol/sequences/Query');
>  9 | var Util             = require('util');
  |                                 ^
 10 |
 11 | module.exports = Connection;
 12 | Util.inherits(Connection, Events.EventEmitter);

at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:158:15)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:231:43)
at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
at resolve (C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
at C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
at resolveDependencies (C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
at processModule (C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
at async addDependency (C:\Users\Dell\React Native Projects\Sign_Up\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

Although I have already installed mysql. Is there any solution?

Comment: This is in relation to the Node [`util`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) library. Are you using Node?

Comment: yes, I am using nodejs

Comment: The next question is, are you *sure*? Node ships with `util` bundled so if it's missing that's very strange. Maybe update it to see if it got deleted somehow.

Comment: Actually, I have realized that some of the modules or packages like `util` have not been installed. Is there any solution for installing some missing modules that haven't been installed and I don't know about it? Because if I just use command `npm i <package -name>` on every missing module, that would be a time waste, since I am continuously getting these packages error.

Comment: Since `util` is fundamentally core to NPM, and I've never seen an install without it, I can only presume your installation got mangled somehow. I'd pull and reinstall Node entirely. It's probably time to do that anyway, as it gets updated frequently. If you still don't get a working `util`, the next question would be "What installation method did you use?" The [usual downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) should do the job.

Comment: I didn't understand to your question. I normally install node packages using `npm i ` command.

Comment: This isn't a package, this is *Node itself*.

Comment: Sorry, `npm i <package -name>` I mean

Comment: Again, not a package. This should be part of Node.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246899/discussion-between-aahil-alwani-and-tadman).